# wxpython filecopy progress bar

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, file-copying

Friends, kindly help me how to update the progress bar in WX Widgets python while copying folder in windows. i tried searching a lot.
Im gud to python, but not so expert in it.  just thought to switch from console python programming to gui programming.   Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance!
Ganesh R

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ProgressDialog's Update](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ProgressDialog-class.html#Update) function, or [UpdatePulse](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ProgressDialog-class.html#Pulse) if you just need to show the user that something's going on.

```
pulse_dlg = wx.ProgressDialog(title="Dialog Title", message="Dialog Message", maximum=100)
# Some stuff happens
for i in range(10):
    wx.MilliSleep(250)
    pulse_dlg.Update(10*i)
```

You can also allow the user to abort the operation, check out [Mike Driscoll's excellent tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/10/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-2-of-2/) on the subject.

Comment: thank u.. but one problem.. when i post my copytree(source, destination) syntax in the place of "# Some stuff happens" the progress bar starts after finishing the copy of folder and its contents... Will you kindly explain how to integrate both copytree(source, destination) and progress bar... ie, copy the folder and its contents, simultaneously the progress bar also should show the progress.

Comment: If you're using [shutil.copytree](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#module-shutil), it looks like you can specify a copy function (it defaults to copy2).  So one way to do it might be to specify your own copy function with a callback that reports when a file's been copied, number of bytes copied, etc.  Or use [threads](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading) to copy in one thread and monitor # files/bytes in destination.

Comment: Could u kindly write down the coding with a copy2 call back function which updates the progress bar, while copying a folder and its contents..? I'm not an expert in python..

Comment: Correction - looks like Python 3 allows you to specify a copy function but Python 2.7 doesn't.  So the easiest thing to do is probably to write a slightly modified version of copytree ([source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py)) to have it report back when a file's been copied.  I'll post a demo below.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own very-slightly-modified version of [copytree](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py) that'll help:

```
import shutil
import os.path
import os

def file_copied():
    print "File copied!"

# Usage example:  copytree(src, dst, cb=file_copied)
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None, cb=None):
    """Recursively copy a directory tree using copy2().

    The destination directory must not already exist.
    If exception(s) occur, an Error is raised with a list of reasons.

    If the optional symlinks flag is true, symbolic links in the
    source tree result in symbolic links in the destination tree; if
    it is false, the contents of the files pointed to by symbolic
    links are copied.

    The optional ignore argument is a callable. If given, it
    is called with the `src` parameter, which is the directory
    being visited by copytree(), and `names` which is the list of
    `src` contents, as returned by os.listdir():

        callable(src, names) -> ignored_names

    Since copytree() is called recursively, the callable will be
    called once for each directory that is copied. It returns a
    list of names relative to the `src` directory that should
    not be copied.

    XXX Consider this example code rather than the ultimate tool.

    """
    names = os.listdir(src)
    if ignore is not None:
        ignored_names = ignore(src, names)
    else:
        ignored_names = set()

    os.makedirs(dst)
    errors = []
    for name in names:
        if name in ignored_names:
            continue
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
            else:
                # Will raise a SpecialFileError for unsupported file types
                shutil.copy2(srcname, dstname)
                if cb is not None:
                    cb()
        # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
        # continue with other files
        except Error, err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
        except EnvironmentError, why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
    try:
        shutil.copystat(src, dst)
    except OSError, why:
        if WindowsError is not None and isinstance(why, WindowsError):
            # Copying file access times may fail on Windows
            pass
        else:
            errors.extend((src, dst, str(why)))
    if errors:
        raise Error, errors
```

All this code does differently than the original copytree is make a call to a specified function after it copies a file.  So in your case in place of file_copied() you could have it Update() the dialog, or update a count of the number of files successfully copied, etc.

Comment: thnk u for your help.. when i inserted your code into my python 2.7 i got the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\tr.py", line 131, in createctrl
    self.copytree(source, destination)
  File "C:\Python27\tr.py", line 82, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, main found

im attaching my python script here.. i dont know how to paste a lengthy coding here, when i do it shows "-4521 characters" here..  kindly download it and add the progress bar func too https://rapidshare.com/files/3443229017/tr.py

Comment: Looks like you're running afoul of indentation for one, check to make sure you're only using Tabs or space characters but not both and make sure the main class' methods are all indented to the same level.  Because you made copytree a method you need to change its declaration to e.g. `def copytree(self, src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None, cb=None)`.  I'd also suggest having a look at a good tutorial to get started, [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) is a good one.